# Getting invalid signature error when I send GET request in postman with authorization

Tags: laravel, postman

I have an email verification method, when I register the user it sends the email normally, I want to test the route `email/verify/{id}`, that triggers when the user clicks the verification link, but I'm having issues with the postman request, it says that I have an invalid signature when I send the authorization token, it throws a different error if i remove it (403, Unauthorized)

My route

```
Route::prefix('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth:api'], function(){
        Route::get('user', 'Auth\AuthController@user');
        Route::get('email/verify/{id}', 'Auth\VerificationController@verify')->name('verification.verify');
        Route::get('email/resend', 'Auth\VerificationController@resend');
    });
});
```

VerificationController

```
public function verify(Request $request){
        if ($request->route('id') == $request->user()->getKey() &&
            $request->user()->markEmailAsVerified()){
                event (new Verified($request->user()));
            }

        return response()->json('verified');
    }

    public function resend(Request $request){
        if ($request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail()){
            return response()->json('already_verified', 422);
        }

        $request->user()->sendEmailVerificationNotification();

        return response()->json([
            'notified'
        ]);
    }

    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('auth:api');
        $this->middleware('signed')->only('verify');
        $this->middleware('throttle:6,1')->only('verify', 'resend');
    }
```

I'm sending the request in postman like this:
[image]

I don't know if I'm doing the request wrong or there is something wrong with my code. Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have `signed` middleware which require another of `GET` parameter.
you can get the signed url by this laravel function
 `URL::signedRoute('verification.verify', []);` and use that url in postman

Edit for summary:
must set `env.APP_URL` to have same port for the `signedRoute` function to works

Comment: Like this? https://imgur.com/OyfWXO9 
But I get the same error

Comment: at the moment, nothing, I had the signature there at the beginning but i got the invalid signature error so i removed it

Comment: so is it your solution to remove the ```middleware```? if you want to try, the 2nd parameter if signedRoute is the ```GET parameter```of the URL, so u can put ```[id=>40]```, become like this ```URL::signedRoute('verification.verify', ["id"=>40]);```

Comment: commenting out the middleware worked, is there something wrong with doing that though? I don't know if removing that middleware would cause a security issue or something, it's the first time I use Laravel as API

Comment: yes it would cause security issue, verify is somehow you give the authority to the person to change your database of validation. without signed url everyone can brute force your URL.. just try my comment with passing the 2nd parameter ```["id"=>40]```

Comment: I generated the signed URL like this: https://imgur.com/rp91lLr , put it in postman like this: https://i.imgur.com/OyfWXO9.png but same error

Comment: @FlowMafia of course, it will be wrong, your parameter first is ```id=>40``` but your request is ```id=>42```, it is the point of ```signed route```, all must matched

Comment: sorry I messed up and sent the wrong images: https://imgur.com/a/OigpbZr

Comment: i think your ```port``` is the only difference, try edit your ```env.APP_URL=http://localhost:8000/``` so that the ```signedRoute function``` return that also

Comment: it finally worked! thank you so much for your time and your help

Comment: welcome, this interesting also, i never use artisan serve before. so i never had port